# spring transactionManager make StringRedisTemplate get no data in Service

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-redis

In Controller, can get redis data

In Service,can't get
my service method begin with  "get"

if  add  `<tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>` in transactionManager can get data
[image]

[image]

Comment: don't laugh at me

Comment: if  add "tx:method name="get*" read-only="true""